# Is there an pandas function to compare with diff column value in each row?

Tags: python, pandas

how to drop diff colume have some values rows:

like this:

```
cod sto POS BDP TMS
30C0    A89R    29  30  30
30C0    A89R    27  27  27
30C0    A89S    10  12  12
30C0    A89S    8   8   8
30C0    A89T    6   9   9
30C0    A89U    15  15  15
30C0    A89V    7   8   8
30C0    A89V    6   13  13
30C0    A89W    6   6   6
30C0    A89W    4   4   4
30C0    A89X    18  15  15
30C0    A89Y    25  27  27
30C0    A89Y    13  13  13
30C0    A89Z    15  17  17
30C0    A89Z    9   10  10
30C0    A900    6   6   6
```

desired get this:

```
30C0    A89R    29  30  30
30C0    A89S    10  12  12
30C0    A89T    6   9   9
30C0    A89V    7   8   8
30C0    A89V    6   13  13
30C0    A89X    18  15  15
30C0    A89Y    25  27  27
30C0    A89Z    15  17  17
30C0    A89Z    9   10  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check with `nunique`

```
yourdf=df[df.iloc[:,2:].nunique(1).gt(1)].copy()
yourdf
Out[565]: 
     cod   sto  POS  BDP  TMS
0   30C0  A89R   29   30   30
2   30C0  A89S   10   12   12
4   30C0  A89T    6    9    9
6   30C0  A89V    7    8    8
7   30C0  A89V    6   13   13
10  30C0  A89X   18   15   15
11  30C0  A89Y   25   27   27
13  30C0  A89Z   15   17   17
14  30C0  A89Z    9   10   10
```